# iptables FORWARD chain set to DROP, rules for tagged traffic don´t forward pakets from one interface to another

Tags: docker, iptables, ubuntu-20.04, netfilter, vlan

I already searched everywhere, also on stackoverflow but didn´t find an anwser. I tried a lot and didn´t see something like that prior.

**Host01:
**
Has two functions:

1. Act as a docker host (https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#docker-on-a-router=
2. IP-Forwarding (iptables) traffic between eth_net_0/vlan100@eth_net_0 <-> eth_inet_1/eth_inet_2

Runs: Ubuntu 20.04 (5.4.0-135-generic)

Host01 should forward traffic:

eth_net_0 <-> eth_inet_1
vlan100@eth_net_0 <-> eth_inet_2

eth_inet_1:

- NAT/MASQ
- DHCP

eth_inet_2

- static IP
- within netplan static nameserver definition
- within netplan static default route to 0.0.0.0 via 172.16.0.1/24 with metric 1000

In case both eth_inet_1/_2 are connected to internet eth_inet_1 will be chosen because of higher metric for default route in routing table.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx            xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x            x            x            x
x DSL-Router x            x LTE-Router x <-- (192.168.0.1/24)
x            x            x            x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx            xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       |                         |
       |                         |                          
       |                         | <-- (192.168.0.0/24)
       |                         |
       |                         |
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  x   (NAT)                  (NAT)      x     
  x eth_inet_1      eth_inet_2  x <-- (static: 192.168.0.100)
  x (DHCP)                              x
  x                                     x
  x     Router/Docker Host          x
  x              (Host01)               x
  x                                     x                   
  x eth_net_0   vlan@100eth_net_0   x
  x                                     x
  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                     |
                     | <-- (Tagged & Untagged Traffic)
                     | Host01 
                     |   -> eth_net_0:         10.0.0.1 
                     |   -> vlan100@eth_net_0: 10.100.0.1
                     |
         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         x                        x
         x  Switch                x
         x Portbased VLAN         x
         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
             |                 |
 VLAN100     |                 | <-- VLAN1
 untagged--> |                 |     untagged (native VLAN)
             |                 |
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx         xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      x            x         x            x
      x PC01       x         x PC02       x 
      x            x         x            x
      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx         xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

      PC01:                  PC02:
      10.100.0.50/24         10.0.0.50/24
```

Note: default interfaces get renamed by netplan at startup by matching NIC MAC-Addresses to configure and rename interfaces.

**What I did so far:**

**1.** Enable ip_forwarding: (yes I also edited /etc/sysctl.conf and uncommented "#net.ip4.ip_forward=1" to make changes persistent)
milkreis@host01:~$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

**2.** Enable NAT:
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth_inet_1 -m comment --comment "Allow Masquerading" -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A POSTROUTING -o eth_inet_2 -m comment --comment "Allow Masquerading" -j MASQUERADE

**3.** Define iptables rules:
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-001 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-001 -j DOCKER 
-A FORWARD -i br-001 ! -o br-001 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-001 -o br-001 -j ACCEPT
...
-A DOCKER -d 172.16.0.2/32 ! -i br-001 -o br-001 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 51000 -j ACCEPT
...
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-001 ! -o br-001 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
...
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-001 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
...
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth_inet_1 -o eth_net_0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth_net_0 -o eth_inet_1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
...
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth_inet_1 -o eth_net_0.100 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth_net_0.100 -o eth_inet_1 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
...
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth_inet_2 -o eth_net_0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth_net_0 -o eth_inet_2 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
...
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth_inet_2 -o eth_net_0.100 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth_net_0.100 -o eth_inet_2 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
...
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN

The DOCKER rules have been set automatically by docker. I followed the advice to but my forward rules under the DOCKER-USER chain in order to be forwarded.

Unless "-P FORWARD ACCEPT" is set to ACCEPT forwarding works as expected. As soon as docker deamon is loaded it sets "-P FORWARD DROP". Now the **strange behavior kicks in**.

Traffic from PC02 traversing from eth_net_0 to any of the eth_inet_1/2 interfaces gets forwarded by host01 with no problem. Ping from PC02 -> 192.168.0.1 (LTE-Router) **is OK**.

Traffic from PC01 traversing from **vlan100@eth_net_0** to any of the eth_inet_1/2 interfaces will NOT gets forwarded by host01. Ping from PC02 -> 192.168.0.1 (LTE-Router) is **NOT OK**.

I tried it also with just eth_inet_2 connected, but with no success. I wireshark running on PC01 a can see the ping requests be sent. On eth_net_0 with "tcp_dump -i eth_net_0 icmp" I can see the inbound requests but on the eth_inet_2 I don´t see any.

When defining the iptables I found out, that the interface names are allowed to have a maximum character length of 15 Bytes + (1 Byte for '\0'). Thats why:

"-A DOCKER-USER -i vlan100@eth_net_0 -o eth_inet_2 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT" will throw an error. So changing vlan100@eth_net_0 -> eth_net_0.100 fixes that.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. With netplan, I rename interfaces based on its MAC addresses. But for VLANs (virtual interfaces) the interface name is just the name of the virtual interface s.a. vlan100 instead of eth_net_0.100. The interfaces and directly connected networks can be seen when typing "route -n".